# How to set an alias so that it will change directory and run a sh file

Tags: linux, shell, command, alias

I want to have an alias which will do:

```
>>>cd $MYUSR
>>>bin/start.sh -t
```

How can I set it? I use bash shell.

Best Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong with the obvious?

```
alias example='cd $MYUSR ; ./bin/start.sh -t'
```

To make it permanent you can add it to ~/.bashrc

Comment: "test" is a terrible name for an alias.  You really want the "test" command to be the expected command.