# Script to change the directory path

Tags: shell

I was trying the below program,
This is a simple script, to cd into a folder

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /root/
```

But this below command , doesnt get into the folder

**EDITED**

```
#!/bin/bash
alias ex="cd /fs/fm"
alias ex1="source setenv"
alias ex2="cd /fs/fm/tests"
alias ex3="runtest"
```

Comment: `#! /bin/bash` is wrong, remove the space after `!`. Also, note that `cd` will be performed within the scope of the script (another shell), so that it won't `cd` your current shell. You maybe want to use an alias http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008648/how-to-set-an-alias-so-that-it-will-change-directory-and-run-a-sh-file

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
alias ex="cd /fs/fm"
alias ex1="source setenv"
alias ex2="cd /fs/fm/tests"
alias ex3="runtest"

Comment: I dont get any errors. But the commands are not set at the path cd'ed

Comment: You can either create a script or set aliases. But do not create an alias within an script, because they will only last during the script execution time. Just store these aliases in your `~/.bashrc` so that you can use them any time after log in.

Comment: How to use these aliases inside the script

Answer (score 1):

To get into `/root/` you should make sure that you have permissions. It's accessible if you're running as root itself but if you're running as a normal user you should consider becoming root first. One way is to use `sudo`:

```
sudo bash script.sh
```

And again, make sure your script is in UNIX format. Certainly you can't change to `/root/\r`.

```
sed -i 's|\r||' script.sh
dos2unix script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This will never work The script you're running is a separate process, when it finishes you get back to the original environment (cwd, enviroment variables, etc...).

Create an alias:

```
alias r="cd /root"
```

or execute the script within your shell:

```
. myscript
```

Note: `.` is a synonym for `source`.

Comment: I wanted to write a script that gets into a dir, sets a command and then changes into the other directory and executes two more commands

Comment: @angus: your original question stated something completely different.

Comment: Yeah , sorry , I was trying a simple program to get into a dir .